# What is difference between executefunc and executeordelayuntilscriptloaded?

Tags: client-object-model

**Execute func:**

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function () { console.log("Initiating SP.ClientContext") });
```

**ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded:**

```
SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(someFunction,"sp.js");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded` only works with scripts which are loaded by default on the page (OnDemand=False). 
Its sole purpose is to make sure that the function is called only after the script has completed loading. 
`executeFunc` works with scripts which are not loaded on the page by default (OnDemand=True). 
Its job is to load the mentioned script on the page and then call the function.

Comment: What is this concept of OnDemand?