# Difference between SP.SOD.executeFunc & other methods

Tags: javascript

I am confused about the idea of `SP.SOD.executeFunc` and other ways of referencing JavaScript, like:

- `SP.SOD.execute`
- `SP.SOD.executeFunc`
- `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded`
- `SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded`
- `LoadSodByKey`

I have read this post: [What is difference between executefunc and executeordelayuntilscriptloaded?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/96942/what-is-difference-between-executefunc-and-executeordelayuntilscriptloaded), but there's no detail.

Answer (score 5):

**execute :**
Executes the specified function in the specified file with the optional arguments.

**executeFunc:**
Ensures that the specified file that contains the specified function is loaded and then runs the specified callback function.

**executeOrDelayUntilEventNotified :** 
Executes the specified function if the specified event has occurred; otherwise, adds the function to the pending job queue.

**executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded :**
Executes the specified function if the file containing it is loaded; otherwise, adds it to the pending job queue

**LoadSodByKey :**
function provided by the SharePoint JavaScript framework in order to dynamically load the script.

Comment: Thank you Akshay, but the function doesn't have to be inside the file. I can call a function but make sure another file like sp.js is loaded, are you referring to case like this or referring to the function inside the same file exactly?

Comment: Good question!!